# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Out of range

Tags: android, android-layout, realm, jdbcrealm

This is for app android, running Android studio, db realm and sql server. i need help

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_employee);
    toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    preferences = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_LOGIN, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    singleItem = new ArrayList<>();
    RealmResults<MdtmMandoranEmployeeDetail> resultEmployeeDetails = realm.where(MdtmMandoranEmployeeDetail.class)
            .findAll().sort("employeename");
    adapterListPemanen = new AdapterListPemanen(this, singleItem, this);
    initVerticalRecycler();
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        DataPemanen data = realm.where(DataPemanen.class)
                .equalTo("nik", resultEmployeeDetails.get(i).getEmployeeid())
                .findFirst();
        if (data == null) {
            singleItem.add(new MdtmMandoranEmployeeDetail(resultEmployeeDetails.get(i).getMandoranemployeeid(),
                    resultEmployeeDetails.get(i).getEmployeeid(),
                    resultEmployeeDetails.get(i).getEmployeename()));
        }
    }
}
```

Error Log

```
E/REALM_JNI: jni: ThrowingException 2, Out of range  in /Users/cm/Realm/realm-java/realm/realm-library/src/main/cpp/io_realm_internal_OsResults.cpp line 102(requested: 0 valid: 0), .
    Exception has been thrown: Out of range  in /Users/cm/Realm/realm-java/realm/realm-library/src/main/cpp/io_realm_internal_OsResults.cpp line 102(requested: 0 valid: 0)
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.hpi.android.bkm, PID: 16623
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.hpi.android.bkm/com.hpi.android.bkm.ui.main.input_pengiriman_hasil_panen.ListEmployeeActivity}: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Out of range  in /Users/cm/Realm/realm-java/realm/realm-library/src/main/cpp/io_realm_internal_OsResults.cpp line 102(requested: 0 valid: 0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2805)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2883)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1613)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6523)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:857)
     Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Out of range  in /Users/cm/Realm/realm-java/realm/realm-library/src/main/cpp/io_realm_internal_OsResults.cpp line 102(requested: 0 valid: 0)
        at io.realm.internal.OsResults.nativeGetRow(Native Method)
        at io.realm.internal.OsResults.getUncheckedRow(OsResults.java:325)
        at io.realm.OrderedRealmCollectionImpl.get(OrderedRealmCollectionImpl.java:124)
        at io.realm.RealmResults.get(RealmResults.java:62)
        at com.hpi.android.bkm.ui.main.input_pengiriman_hasil_panen.ListEmployeeActivity.onCreate(ListEmployeeActivity.java:64)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7023)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7014)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2758)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2883) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1613) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6523) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:857)
```

Comment: Now would be a great time to learn how to use a debugger.  Add a breakpoint to this method, and step through the code to see exactly what the problem is.  Note that you are in the best position to answer this question, by the way.

Comment: On what criteria you have used for loop with count 50?? It should be based on list count from which you are retrieving data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You `for` loop should be,

```
for (int i = 0; i < resultEmployeeDetails.size(); i++) {
  ....
  ....
}
```